# Shooting sprite android

Tags: java, android, sprite

I am developing an Android game in java where I will have a sprite that follows the user's finger and is supposed to fire a bullet every second.  In other words, I am trying to attach a bitmap that moves up every second.  The bitmap starts at the x and y coordinates of the main character sprite.  I can't get it to draw more than one missile at a time, and I have run out of ideas of how to do so.  I have tried so many things, and I really could use some help.

By the way, my Main Game Panel class extends a surfaceView and implements a SurfaceHolder.Callback:

```
public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you please paste your drawing code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to have the ability to shoot more than 1 bullet at a time? You can use a Vector or Array to do this. With an Array you can set a default amount of visible bullets and in a Vector you could have as mant bullets that your finger is capable of producing.

Here's my code that I use to generate lasers (I store the values in an Array).

```
public void updatePlayerLaser(boolean shootLaser) {
        // Check if a new Laser should be created
        if(shootLaser == true) {
            if(timeLastCreatedLaser + 100 < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                timeLastCreatedLaser = System.currentTimeMillis();
                boolean createdNewLaser = false;
                for(int i = 0; i < this.amountOfVisibleLasers; i++) {
                    if(createdNewLaser == false) {
                        if(holderLaser[i].isDisposed()) {
                            this.generateNewLaser(i);
                            createdNewLaser = true;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Update all the other Lasers
        for(int i = 0; i < this.amountOfVisibleLasers; i++) {
            if(holderLaser[i].isDisposed() == false) {
                holderLaser[i].update();
            }

        }

    }
```

Disposed in this contexts means that the laser is dead, thus making space for a new laser to take the old lasers spot.

Comment: Yes!!  Thank you so much! I love you.